# How to pass arguments to node script from launch configuration in vscode

Tags: node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code

Why isn't my launch configuration in vscode picking up on `args` key?
vscode Version: 1.63.2

### launch.json

```json
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "command": "node ${workspaceFolder}/test.js",
      "args": ["foo"],
      "name": "test",
      "request": "launch",
      "type": "node-terminal",
    },
  ]
}
```

### test.js

```js
console.log("running script");
console.log(process.argv);
```

I press play from debug sidebar and get this in console:

```
$ node /Users/acohen/mp/mobileapp-client-tests/test.js
Debugger attached.
running script
[
  '/Users/acohen/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.2/bin/node',
  '/Users/acohen/mp/mobileapp-client-tests/test.js'
]
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
```

Why isn't "foo" passed as an argument?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a config example that worked for me:

```
{
"configurations": [
{
    "name": "Launch Program",
    "args": ["foo"],
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/test.js",
    "request": "launch",
    "type": "pwa-node"
}
]
```

}

Comment: with pwa-node, this run config doesn't do anything. It doesn't even print to the console. And no errors.

Comment: It does not open separate terminal, you should check out debug console window

Comment: Using pwa-node totally doesn't work for me. The debugger doesn't even break. If I change it to node-terminal, it breaks and works, but for some reason I can't pass arguments.

Comment: If you want to run script inside terminal, you should skip debugger and just run it from terminal.. "node test,js foo"
Since you want to use debugger for it, this is the solution, try to set breakpoint where you console.log args and you will see that value is there.
and of course debugger just exits, it just prints values and it is done

Comment: I don't understand. It doesn't hit the breakpoint.

I want to run the command line program from the debugger from within vscode and put break points in. This works using type "node-terminal" but the args don't get passed.

Comment: Weird. I completely uninstalled vscode, reinstalled and it works now. Maybe there was an extension that was interferring.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, what I ultimately wanted to do was run a complex npm script and debug it. I re-installed vscode, and found some good docs here:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_launch-configuration-support-for-npm-and-other-tools

and here for using nvm:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_multi-version-support

My `launch.json` looks like this:

where `test_ios` is the npm script to debug and `14.17.3` is the version of node (installed with nvm) to use:

```json
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Launch via npm",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
      "runtimeArgs": ["run-script", "test_ios"],
      "runtimeVersion": "14.17.3"
    }
  ]
}
```